# Python: Inserting text after a tab in a text file

Tags: python, text, seek

I want to insert some text after a tab character in a textfile. How can I do this in python?

I have tried using Python seek() function. But is does not seem to take `'\t'`(for tab) as an argument.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to insert after all tab characters, or a specific one?

Comment: I want to insert after the first tab in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use seek for that. It is used to position the file cursor at a certain position in a file. (I.e. set the cursor to a position as a count of characters).

If you really want to insert you have to rewrite everything behind the cursor position anyway, otherwise your insertion overwrites bits of the file.

One way to do this is this:

```
fd = open(filename, "r+")
text = fd.read()
text = text.replace("\t", "\t" + "Inserted text", 1)
fd.seek(0)
fd.write(text)
fd.close()
```

Comment: I think you wanted to do `txt.read()` instead of `txt.read` and `.replace("\t", "\t"+INSERTED_TEXT, 1)` instead of `.replace("\t", "\t", 1)`

Comment: @Elisha: thanks for spotting this, and feel free to just correct obvious mistakes like this, after all this is why you can edit others posts (I believe).

Answer (score 1):

```
text_to_insert = 'some text'
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    tab_position = text.find('\t')
    head, tail = text[:tab_position+1], text[tab_position+1:]
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(head + text_to_insert + tail)
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you'll need to re-write the file for that insertion. A possible solution would be to save the file into a string, replace the first occurrence of a tab, and write the derived string into a new file

```
file_string = open(somefile).read()

modified_string = file_string.replace("\t", "\t" + "what you want to insert", 1)

with open(new_file, "w") as mod_file:
     mod_file.write(modified_string)
```

Note that the third argument of the `replace` method will only replace the first tab it will find in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for lines in textfile:
...     lines = lines.split("\t")
...     lines[1] = "This is your inserted string after first tab"
```

Comment: This will actually replace all content between the first and second tab, while the OP wants to insert something after the first tab.

Comment: True. Kinda thought that was intended, but apparently not. Thanks